# Why does the Hubble constant have a subscript zero?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, physical-constants

The title says it all. Why is the Hubble constant written $H_0$ and not just $H$? What is the purpose of that subscript $_0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hubble parameter is defined as $\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$, where $a$ is the scale factor in the Friedmann-Robertson-Walker metric:
$$g_{\mu\nu} \, \mathrm{d}x^{\mu} \, \mathrm{d}x^{\nu}=c^2 \, \mathrm{d}t^2-a^2 \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}r^2}{1-kr^2}+r^2\mathrm{d}\Omega ^2 \right) \,.$$

When you put this metric into Einstein Field Equation, you will get an equation that describes how $a$ evolves with time $t$. Thus in general the Hubble parameter is a function of time.

$H_0$ is used to indicate the actual value of the Hubble parameter, measured at our time.

Answer (score 2):

The Hubble "constant" is not a constant; it changes with time and should be referred to as the Hubble parameter. You can find a discussion/plots of this variation with time at [How does the Hubble parameter change with the age of the universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136056/how-does-the-hubble-parameter-change-with-the-age-of-the-universe)

The value of the Hubble parameter at the present epoch is represented with $H_0$.